# Trouble accessing mysql database and printing out matching results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, url

I wrote this code to pull from a image links database to make it easier to update weather links. However, it won't print the image link into the urlspace:

```
<?php
/* This code establishes MySQL connection,creates a function that pulls URLs from database to update picture file ? */

$datab ="weather";
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$datab", "***", "*****");
function rainmaker($fname) {
$sql = $connect->query("SELECT link FROM `radar3`  WHERE `name` = `$fname`");
while($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$url1 = urlencode($result['name']);
print $url1;
};
?>


    //URL where the image link will be printed:

      <P><A HREF="../showImage.php?&url=<?=rainmaker('**$fname**')?>.php">North Plains</A></P>
```

Instead it merely prints the php function name code.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: For new development, you really should use the mysqli extension, intstead of the mysql_ extension).  From php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php): "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."

Comment: Your code is missng the part where you actually get the result from your SQL query. Please check `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or something similar. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I did what you asked and converted it to PDO.Still need help, please remove hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks to escape table and column names, not quotes

```
SELECT link FROM `radar3` WHERE `name` = '$fname'
```

Use quotes only for static strings in your query.

Comment: Also not using short tags `<?=` may be suggested here.